# Is this sentence grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction, sentence-usage

The Sentence:

```
If there is any person I wanted to share my small success with is then it has to be you.
```

Is this sentence wrong? How could I rephrase this sentence?

Comment: For starters, you've got an extra *is*.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Unfortunately proofreading topics are off-topic here. You will have more success asking questions like this over at Lang8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rephrase to:

> If I could share my success with anyone, it would be you.